# Neovim Slow Cursor Blinking

Tags: vim, macvim, neovim

I'm trying to switch from Macvim to Neovim, but running into an issue that I can't figure out. I can't get `guicursor` to fully work. I say fully work because *some* of it does, e.g. setting `ver25` or `hor25`, changing colors, or setting `blinkon0` to disable blinking.

But the blinking timings aren't working like they do in Macvim. In Neovim, it seems to be the same speed no matter what I try. And the `blinkwait` seems to **change** sometimes. Sometimes it waits longer than other times (you can see this when I do `o` in the demo). This gives the very annoying effect of feeling laggy.

Please see demo: https://youtu.be/oKruKQ9CESY

I tried iTerm2 (which I use), Terminal, and kitty - same results.

I tried setting in init.vim, CLI flag, and in nvim's command mode.

I tried the latest stable (0.8.3) and also HEAD:

```
❯ nvim --version
NVIM v0.9.0-dev-1324+ge30cc8be1-Homebrew
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
```